# How can display txt file in terminal through a linux command?

Tags: linux

I forgotten how do this...

the command is something who this:
~$"command" gladiator.txt

When a Roman general is betrayed and his family murdered by an emperor's corrupt son, he comes to Rome as a gladiator to seek revenge.
~$

Comment: I thought that command is echo but I tried and this is not works.

Comment: learn to use internet. You could have got this on first link on google.

Comment: Specifically https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=How+can+display+txt+file+in+terminal+through+a+linux+command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For small file

```
cat fileName.txt
```

or

```
cat path/fileName.txt
```

directly shows a text file in the terminal.

For large file

```
less fileName.txt
```

or

```
less path/fileName.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see more information here also:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1WseCc3_XA about this command

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$ cat file.txt
```

have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

cat FILENAME

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

enter these in your terminal

```
cat textfile.txt
```

cat command shows the contents of a file